# Call instance method from instance method

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, mongoose

I'd like to call method1 from within method2. Not sure how to access it. I receive:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'method1' of undefined

```
TestSchema.methods = {
  method1: () => {
      return true;
  },
  method2: () => {
    if(this.method1()){
        console.log('It works!');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: How `method2` is called ?

Comment: Test test = new Test(); test.method2();

Comment: @70656e6973 What is `Test`?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin The TestSchema is the model of 'Test' object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the arrow function. It uses the `this` context from the lexical scope of the function definition. And it's undefined in the `strict mode` you're using.

Use regular functions:

```
TestSchema.methods = {
  method1: function() {
      return true;
  },
  method2: function() {
    if(this.method1()){
        console.log('It works!');
    }
  }
};
```

And then make sure to call the function as a method on the object:

```
TestSchema.methods.method2();
```

You can find more explanations about arrow functions as methods [here](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#72pitfalldefiningmethodwitharrowfunction).

Comment: So far for trying to keep up with ES6. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs simply because of the arrow functions. The arrow function expression doesn't bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super` and `new.target`.

Also, you shouldn't use `function` keyword to overcome this issue. The best solution is to use [`Shorthand method names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

```
TestSchema.methods = {
  method1(){
    return true;
  },
  method2(){
    if (this.method1()) {
      console.log('It works!');
    }
  }
};
TestSchema.methods.method2();
```

Comment: Appreciate the further explanation you're giving + other workaround!